# efficiently move environment from inside function to global environment

Tags: r, environment

I have a function that creates an environment within it and i wish to assign that environment to the global environment. At present i do this by assigning the environment to `globalenv()` as the final step -- as follows:

```
funfun <- function(inc = 1){
    dataEnv <- new.env()
    dataEnv$d1 <- 1 + inc
    dataEnv$d2 <- 2 + inc
    dataEnv$d3 <- 2 + inc
    assign('dataEnv', dataEnv, envir = globalenv())
}
```

It feels like i should be able to do something to make `dataEnv` persisit when the function `funfun` ends (to save copying the environment at the end) however my attempts, such as `dataEnv <- new.env(parent = globalenv())`, have not worked.

Why does it fail? Is this possible?

Also, what is the most efficient way of doing this?

My tables are very large at times, and the copying will become an issue as the project grows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your environment is not being destroyed when you exit the function. You just need to return a reference to it.

```
funfun <- function(inc = 1){
  dataEnv <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
  dataEnv$d1 <- 1 + inc
  dataEnv$d2 <- 2 + inc
  dataEnv$d3 <- rnorm(10000)
  return(dataEnv)
}


myEnv <- funfun()
object.size(myEnv)
```

Get some stuff out

```
head(myEnv$d3)
```

Comment: Is the return required? Or is it enough just to have dataEnv as the final line of the function? I am eternally unsure about return statements in r.

Comment: return is not required, you can just put the value at the end. If you have doubts about style I recently read this http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml . I think that they do use `return` in some example. But is just a matter of taste.

Comment: This seems to raise a "garbage collection"  question.  Suppose you don't return the environment reference?  How do you detect the existence of `dataEnv` so if nothing else you can delete it when not wanted?

Comment: I am not any expert but If you dont return any reference it will still be garbage collect when gc() is called because no reference exists in the already reachable objects. When the garbage collector starts a mark-and-sweep algorithm will run, where from a reachable object (the baseEnv for example),  all the objects with references will be found recursively and flaged as reachable. Since we did not return a reference, to the global env in this case, dataEnv will not be marked as reachable and collected.

Comment: sorry, 'it will still be garbage collect' should be 'then it will be garbage collected'

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I want to assign something to a global environment I just do

```
varname <<- value
```

Comment: Wont this copy the environment that is inside the function as it moves it from inside to outside the closure?

Comment: Yeah.  Personally, I'd go with Usobi's response, but this is what you'd do if you wanted to assign that specific variable name to the global environment (which looks like what you were doing in the code provided).

`myEnv<<-dataEnv` would be the code that does the same thing as above.