# How to find unreferenced environments?

Tags: r, environment

This is a followup to an answer here  [efficiently move environment from inside function to global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177499/efficiently-move-environment-from-inside-function-to-global-environment) , which pointed out that it's necessary to return a reference to an environment which was created inside a function if one wishes to work with the contents of that environment

Is it true that the newly created environment continues to exist if we don't return a reference, and if so how does one track down such an environment, either to access its contents or delete it?

Comment: I don't think this is true. Are you on Windows? You can check this with `memory.size`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde If I interpret Josh's answer correctly, yep it's true.

Comment: yeah, I misread read the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if it was assigned to a symbol somewhere outside of the function's evaluation environment (as it was in the OP's example), an environment will continue to exist. In that sense, an environment is just like any other named R object. (The fact that unassigned environments can be kept in existence by [closures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures) does mean that environments sometimes persist where other types of object wouldn't, but that's not what's happening here.)

```
## OP's example function
funfun <- function(inc = 1){
    dataEnv <- new.env()
    dataEnv$d1 <- 1 + inc
    dataEnv$d2 <- 2 + inc
    dataEnv$d3 <- 2 + inc
    assign('dataEnv', dataEnv, envir = globalenv())  ## Assignment to .GlobalEnv
}
funfun()
ls(env=.GlobalEnv)
# [1] "dataEnv" "funfun" 

## It's easy to find environments assigned to a symbol in another environment,
## if you know which environment to look in.
Filter(isTRUE, eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.environment))
# $dataEnv
# [1] TRUE
```

In the OP's example, it's relatively easy to track down, because the environment was assigned to a symbol in `.GlobalEnv`. In general, though, (and again, just like any other R object) it will be difficult to track down if, for instance, it's assigned to an element in a list or some more complicated structure.

(This, incidentally, is why non-local assignment is usually discouraged in R and other more purely functional languages. When functions only return a value, and that value is only assigned to a symbol via explicit assignments (like `v <- f()`), the effects of executing code becomes a lot easier to reason about and predict. Fewer surprises makes for nicer code!)